# Is it possible to set min-height on a floated div inside another div using percents?

Tags: html, css

Her is my css:

```
html {
/* force document to be 200% of window size */
min-height: 200%;
}
body {
height:auto; 
margin:0 auto;
}
div#wrapper {
/* so that child divs with floats stay contained */
overflow:hidden; 
margin:auto;
min-width:200%;
min-height:200%; /* doesn't work */
background-color:#000;
border:1px solid red;
}
div#content1 {
float:left;
min-width:45%;
min-height:45%; /* doesn't work */
background-color:#555;
border:1px solid green;
}
div#content2 {
float:right;
min-width:45%;
min-height:45%; /* doesn't work */
background-color:#777;
border:1px solid blue;
}
```

And html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content1"></div>
<div id="content2"></div>
</div>
```

I would like for #content1 and #conent2 to always occupy 45% of the window regardless of content. In Firefox, at least, the min-width works but the min-height does not. Is it possible to set a min-height in this situation using percents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the `height` property as a percentage only when the `parent` container is set at a fixed height. In this case, `html` is set to `height:auto` despite your explicit `height:200%`. Thus, having the `wrapper` divider set to a percentage height will not work and the subsequent percentage `min-height` child elements will be ineffective as well.